# local notifications ios 11 in background

Tags: objective-c, cordova, ios11

I prepared iOS app in cordova, I used original Cordova Plugin for Local Notifications. I'm scheduling about 90 local notifications in notification center. It's working on iOS 10, but on iOS 11 not always and on not every device.

For example on my phone I see all notifications - in foreground and background.

On other phone I see notifications only in foreground (inside app), not in background.

Is it an iOS 11 bug?

**UPDATE - SOLVED**

Cordova Plugin for local notifications can only schedule 64 local notifications (like iOS docs limit). So I need to code native module with queue for 64 current local notifications and database to set next local notifications after limit.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue and I'm not finding a solution for it yet!

Comment: On iOS 10 I have the same issue, trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

IOS 11 try use this in - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(showNotical:) withObject:@"Open InBack"];
```

with  method

```
- (void) showNotical:(NSString*)msg <br>
{

    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
    {
            //UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];

    }
    else // iOS 7 or earlier
    {
            //UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
        UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
    }

    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        //    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1];
    localNotification.alertAction = @"test";
    localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",msg];
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName; // den den den
    localNotification.repeatInterval = 7;
        //[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber=1;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

}
```

Comment: shouldn't you be using UNUserNotification framework?

Comment: maybe I do not understand you, I using UIKit framework ,this code run IOS 11 when app in background will show message on screen.

Comment: But since it's deprecated, you never know when will Apple drop support for it.